# Python string with byte array to byte array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cryptography

```
ciphertext = base64.b64decode(xxxxxx) //output is b'148,240,50,66,81,26,240,2,101,31'
bytearray(ciphertext) // output is bytearray(b'148,240,50,66,81,26,240,2,101,31')
```

What am looking for is output of bytearray([148,240,50,66,81,26,240,2,101,31])

Full code:

```
ciphertext = base64.b64decode("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")
```

Comment: Can you please post a repeatable code? i need to know the input var type inside "base64.b64decode()"

Comment: agreed with @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
bytearray(ciphertext)
```

with:

```
bytearray(map(int, ciphertext.split(b',')))
# Or if you prefer genexprs:
bytearray(int(x) for x in ciphertext.split(b','))
```

The former is just converting the raw `bytes` to an equivalent `bytearray`, the latter splits it up by commas and *parses* the components as `int`s.